# Como puedo elevar Math.E a una matriz?

Tags: c#

He usado este código pero no me deja elevar el numero `e` a una matriz ni con `Math.Pow()`, `Math.exp()`. Como puedo hacerlo?? aquí dejo código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
using MathNet.Symbolics;
using MathNet.Numerics.RootFinding;
using NMath;
using MathNet.Filtering.Kalman;
using System.Runtime;
using NLapack.Matrices;
using NLapack.Numbers;


namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double omega = 2 * Math.PI / 24;
            double omegacua = Math.Pow(omega, 2);

            Matrix<double> Ac = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] { { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { (-1 * omegacua), 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 } });

            Matrix<double> A = Math.Exp(Ac);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Obviamente, dudo que ninguna librería standard de .net tenga algo tan sofisticado. Estás usando alguna librería matemática?

Answer (score 1):

Si analizamos la documentacion

[Math.Exp(Double) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.exp?view=netframework-4.5)

observaras que el metodo espera un dato del tipo `double`, no una matriz

Por eso para que funcione deberias iterar cada item de la matriz y realizar el calculo

```
Matrix<double> A = new Matrix<double>[Ac.GetLength(0), Ac.GetLength(1)];
int i = 0;
foreach(var item in Ac){
  int j=0;
  foreach(var item1 in item){
    A[i,j] = Math.Exp(item1);
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

[Using foreach with arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays)

La idea es calcular por cada valor de la matriz iterandola